# How to over-write a label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to write the simplest tkinter window that will show an entry box and a button and the square of whatever number is entered in the entry box.

The code I've written sort of works, except that each new answer is over-written on the previous one so if you have a long number followed by a small number you can see the remains of the old answer underneath the new one.

How could I fix this? Is there a way to cancel the previous label?

```
from tkinter import *

x=Tk()
x.geometry('900x400')
e=Entry(x)
e.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)

def z():
    aa=e.get()
    aa=int(aa)
    aa=aa**2
    l=Label(x, text=aa).place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4)
    e.delete(0, END)

b=Button(x, text='PRESS', command=z).place(relx=0.6, rely=0.2)
x.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change the text of the label rather than creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create mpnew labels. Create the label once, then use the `configure` method to change the text.

```
global l
l = Label(...)
l.pack(...)
...
l.configure(text="some string")
```

As a suggestion: when learning tkinter, ignore `place`. It is much less useful than `pack` and `grid`.

note: you must create the label and then call pack/place/grid on separate lines because pack/place/grid always returns None.

Comment: However, I find that I get the error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'
Same happens with delete, forget, remove and everything else I can think of.

Comment: Separate `l=Label(...).place(...)` into `l=Label(...)` and `l.place(...)`. `place` returns `None`, so you're assigning `None` to `l` instead of the label reference